# Debian 11 fails to update grub configuration

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive, boot, grub

I have the following error when I run an update script with ansible:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...", "Found linux image:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-26-amd64", "Found initrd image:
/boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-26-amd64", "Found linux image:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-19-amd64", "Found initrd image:
/boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-19-amd64", "Warning: os-prober will be
executed to detect other bootable partitions.", "Its output will be
used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot
entries.", "done", "Setting up grub-pc (2.06-3~deb11u6) ...",
"/dev/disk/by-id/ata-CFS3F-MT_32GB_2122072004900007 does not exist
```

The problem is that this server's OS (debian 11) has been installed by cloning an image of another machine. Probably the id of the disk is different:

```
sysoperator@server1:~$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan  3 15:09 ata-CFS3F-MT_32GB_2122072004900022 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  3 15:09 ata-CFS3F-MT_32GB_2122072004900022-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan  3 15:09 ata-Maximus-128GB_20220615100000000127 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  3 15:09 ata-Maximus-128GB_20220615100000000127-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan  3 15:09 wwn-0x5000000000000006 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  3 15:09 wwn-0x5000000000000006-part1 -> ../../sda1
```

Essentially instead of **/dev/disk/by-id/ata-CFS3F-MT_32GB_2122072004900007** grub shall be using **/dev/disk/by-id/ata-CFS3F-MT_32GB_2122072004900022** instead.

I can't find within the documentation where can I replace one id by another and update grub accordingly prior to installing the updates.

EDIT: I know it can manually fixed by running dialog dpkg --configure grub-pc and choose the proper disk but I need to automate this, I have hundreds of servers and can't do this manually...

EDIT2: The server boots properly. It seems it uses the UUID to boot:

```
NAME   FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda
└─sda1 ext4   1.0         6d68a3a0-c63e-4465-b170-4e0b109d973a  101.9G     2% /home
sdb
└─sdb1 ext4   1.0         9ad5ffb5-1a87-49aa-b90b-ffe5ab77d298   20.3G    25% /
```

The boot partition is sdb1, hence the UUID for ata-CFS3F-MT_32GB_2122072004900022 is 9ad5ffb5-1a87-49aa-b90b-ffe5ab77d298. This seems ok:

```
sysoperator@server1:~$ cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep "root 9"
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ad5ffb5-1a87-49aa-b90b-ffe5ab77d298
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ad5ffb5-1a87-49aa-b90b-ffe5ab77d298
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ad5ffb5-1a87-49aa-b90b-ffe5ab77d298
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ad5ffb5-1a87-49aa-b90b-ffe5ab77d298
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ad5ffb5-1a87-49aa-b90b-ffe5ab77d298
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ad5ffb5-1a87-49aa-b90b-ffe5ab77d298
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should first figure out where the disk ID from the original host is actually stored. `grep -r 2122072004900007 /etc` should find that out without too much trouble. Then, once you know where the disk ID is used, you should consider the corrective action needed, given that changing this ID was obviously missed in the post-cloning steps.

Comment: Hey! I solved this. The problem was that though grub was booting properly there were references to the imaged machine's disk on /var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst and /var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.preinst. Delete both files and run dpkg --configure grub-pc and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that though grub was booting properly there were references to the imaged machine's disk on:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.preinst
```

Delete both files and run:

```
dpkg --configure grub-pc
```

and you are good to go

Comment: That's a little bit suspicious. `grub-pc.preinst` and `grub-pc.postinst` should be scripts executed at package installation time, and they should be unmodified from the *.dpkg package, as far as I know. Are you sure that wasn't a "false positive" search hit? But running the `dpkg --configure grub-pc` seems like a valid fix anyway; doing just that might have been enough.